# Kineticjs apply Mask filter to a layer

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

How can we apply Mask filter to a layer. Official documentation shows this:

```
node.cache();
node.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Mask]);
node.threshold(0.1);
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layer.cache();
layer.threshold(260);
layer.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Mask]);
layer.draw();
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/luyola/1/edit?js,output